# Two diode circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes

I made this circuit online and I was trying to analyze it by paper to see how diodes work. I know we assume the position of each diode. I assumed both to be "ON" and I'm just using the ideal model of how it will just short when on, or open circuit when off. But the -10V keeps throwing me off. Can someone show me how to analyze this properly?
[image]

Comment: Does your circuit tool lack the feature to move text around so it doesn't overlap?

Comment: Yes, it seems to. However, what overlaps is irrelevant to the problem, since I want to just use a simplified model.

Comment: What do the red circles do or imply. I've not seen them before other than when I wake up after a big night.

Comment: Just assume the circles after the supply are negative -> GND.

Comment: Looks very close to: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/257725/how-to-analyze-circuits-like-this/

Comment: If the -10V is throwing you, remember that you can always shift all single point voltages by a constant.  In this case you could set the -10V supply to ground, ground to 10V and the 10V supply to 20V.